# Hooking into Linux executable with LD_PRELOAD not work

Tags: c++, linux, hook, game-engine, ld-preload

I have old game and i want to fix core dump of this game. I used gdb to recover game class and create my own shared library .so file.
However, when i run program using LD_PRELOAD, nothing change as i code.
This program runs on Linux 32bit.

```
$ ldd ./jx_linux_y
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77d0000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf77c4000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0xf77be000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf77a3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf76b7000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7674000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7659000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf748e000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77d1000)
```

Please help me to know why. Thank you

I tried to compile my own code:

/usr/bin/gcc -lgcc_s -lstdc++ -m32 -ldl -std=c++11 -fPIC -shared gameserver.cpp -o gameserver.so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "KBuySell.h"

bool KBuySell::Init(void)
{
    printf("===========================\n");
    printf("Test hooking KBuySell::Init\n");
    printf("===========================\n");

    return 1;
};

bool KBuySell::Buy(int nPlayerIdx, int nBuy, int nBuyIdx, int nPlace, int nX, int nY)
{
    printf("===========================\n");
    printf("Test hooking KBuySell::Buy\n");
    printf("===========================\n");

    return 1;
};
```

KBuySell.h

```
#include <map>
#include "KSG_LogFile.h"
#include "KMemFile.h"

class KGoods;
class KItem;
class KTabFile;

enum CurrencyType
{
  CURRENCYTYPE_NONE,
  CURRENCYTYPE_MONEY,
  CURRENCYTYPE_FUYUAN,
  CURRENCYTYPE_COIN,
  CURRENCYTYPE_SCORE,
  CURRENCYTYPE_GOLDCOIN,
  CURRENCYTYPE_SLIVER,
  CURRENCYTYPE_TICKET,
  CURRENCYTYPE_YUANBAO,
  CURRENCYTYPE_GOLDCOIN_NEW,
  CURRENCYTYPE_CONTRIBUTION,
  CURRENCYTYPE_HONOUR,
  CURRENCYTYPE_GOLDCOIN_SCORE,
  CURRENCYTYPE_RESPECT,
  CURRENCYTYPE_REFINING,
  CURRENCYTYPE_ENERGY,
  CURRENCYTYPE_ARENA_CREDITS,
  CURRENCYTYPE_END
};

class KBuySell : public KMemFileNotifyHelper
{
  enum SALE_BEHAVIOR
  {
    BUY,
    SELL
  };

public:
  int **m_ShopGoods;

private:
  KGoods *m_Goods;
  int m_Width;
  int m_Height;
  int m_MaxGoods;
  static KTabFile ms_ItemBusinessShopSetting;
  std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const, int>>> m_mapGoodsName;
  KItem *m_arySaleLogItem;
  int m_nSaleLogItemCount;
  KSG_LogFile m_SaleLogFile;

public:
  KBuySell();
  ~KBuySell();
  bool Init(void);
  int GetWidth(void);
  int GetHeight(void);
  int GetGoodsCount(void);
  KGoods *GetGoods(int);
  KGoods *GetGoods(const char *);
  int GetGoodsIndex(int, int);
  bool BuyCallBack(int, int, int);
  int AddGoodsToPlayer(int, KGoods *, CurrencyType, int, long long, int, int, int);
  void OpenSale(int, int, CurrencyType, int, const char *);
  void OpenItemBussinessSale(int, int, CurrencyType, int, const char *);
  bool Buy(int, int, int, int, int, int);
  bool Sell(int, int, int);
  void CreateStores(int);
  void AddShop2Stores(int, int, const char *, CurrencyType, int, const char *, bool);
  void OpenStores(int);
  void StoresChangeShop(int, int);
  bool WriteLog(int, KItem *, int, CurrencyType, int, KBuySell::SALE_BEHAVIOR, bool);
  bool WriteLog(int, KGoods *, int, CurrencyType, int, KBuySell::SALE_BEHAVIOR, bool);
  bool WriteLog(int, char *);
  static int ItemBusinessShopName2ID(char *);
  bool OnNotifyGoldCoinChangeResult(int, int, int, bool);
  bool OnNotifyBuyItem(int, int, int, long long);
  void ExportGoodsInfo(void);

private:
  bool LoadDataFromFile(void);
  bool RemoveAllData(void);
  virtual bool OnFileChanged(const char *, unsigned long, unsigned long);
  virtual bool OnlyForFileListChanged(void);
  bool InitItemSaleLog(void);
};
```

KMemFile.h

```
class IKMemFileNotify {
  public:
    virtual bool OnFileChanged(const char *, unsigned long, unsigned long);
    virtual bool OnlyForFileListChanged(void);
};


class KMemFileNotifyHelper : public IKMemFileNotify {
  private:
    unsigned long m_dwFileListGUID;
    unsigned long m_dwVerifyCode;

  public:
    KMemFileNotifyHelper(unsigned long);
    ~KMemFileNotifyHelper();
    unsigned long GetMemFileListGUID(void);
    unsigned long GetMemFileVerifyCode(void);
    virtual bool OnFileChanged(const char *, unsigned long, unsigned long);
};
```

KSG_LogFile.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum KE_LOGLEVEL
{
  emLOGLEVEL_FATAL,
  emLOGLEVEL_ERROR,
  emLOGLEVEL_WARN,
  emLOGLEVEL_INFO,
  emLOGLEVEL_DEBUG
};

struct KSG_LogFile
{
private:
  static unsigned int s_uCurDayOfYear;
  FILE *m_pLog;
  unsigned int m_uDayOfYear;
  int m_bFileNameAutoChangeWithDate;
  char m_szFileNameKey[260];
  char m_szSuffixName[20];
  KE_LOGLEVEL m_nLevel;
  size_t m_nFileSize;
  char m_szFile[260];

public:
  KSG_LogFile(char const *);
  ~KSG_LogFile();
  int Init(char const *);
  int InitWithDate(char const *, char const *, int);
  void ChangeLogLevel(KE_LOGLEVEL);
  void printf(const char *, ...);
  void puts(const char *);
  void write_time(void);
  void write_date(void);
  void write_date_time(void);
  void write_date_time_in(long);
  void printf_t(char const *, ...);
  void puts_t(char const *);
  void log(KE_LOGLEVEL, char const *, ...);
  void log_t(KE_LOGLEVEL, char const *, ...);

private:
  void WriteLog(KE_LOGLEVEL, char const *, char *, int);
  void WriteLog(char const *, size_t);
  int OpenNewFile(void);
};
```

Actually resulted: **When buy an item in game, print the message.**

Comment: Are these symbols defined in your preloaded shared library defined and used in the executable? This will not work. Only symbols that are defined in some shared library, and referenced in the executable, can be intercepted using `LD_PRELOAD` trick. Furthermore, even if these are the demangled symbols, unless your C++ compiler is confirmed to be binary ABI-compatible with whatever compiler built that "old game", this is just going to turn a bad situation into worse...

Comment: i tried to reverse and add break point on this function and make sure that these functions are defined.